# Share an App in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, share

I created an App for windows phone. I want to include the feature of Native share option in Windows Phone 8 (while press and holding an app. it shows 1.Pin to Start 2. Rate&review 3. Uninstall and i want to include Share option.)

Is that anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I think these option comes when you download you app from app store. If you have installed developer build then there won't be a Rate & Review option.

Comment: No. Only First 3 options will come. Share is not

Comment: Have you downloaded your app from store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask
            {
                ContentIdentifier = "App ID",  
                ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications
            };

        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Try this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is *Not* possible to add new item in system context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Not Possible. There is no Such Exposed API/Method That Can Do For You.